# my whitelist filter doesnt filter all tags correctly

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tinymce-5

I am trying to filter pasted HTML in tinymce-5. My filter filters almost every tag correctly, but some remain.

For testing please copy the whole page source code.

For testing and reproducing my problem, I recommend copying stuff from the "paste" documentation ( https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/opensource/paste/ ) and looking into console/tinymce`s source code plugin ( < > button )

Filter code:

```
const filterText = (text) => {
            let filteredText = text
                var regex2 = new RegExp("<(\/?).*?>", "gi");
                console.log(text)
                const tags = text.match(/<(\/?).*?>/gi);
                console.log(tags)
                for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                    let matchez = false
                    for (let q = 0; q < whitelist.length; q++) {
                        var regex = new RegExp("<(\/?)" + whitelist[q] + ".*?>", "gi");
                        if (tags[i].match(regex)){
                            console.log(tags[i] + " " + i)
                            matchez = true
                            console.log(matchez)
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log(tags[i])
                        }
                    }
                    if (matchez === false){
                        filteredText = filteredText.replace(tags[i], "")
                    }
                } 
                console.log(filteredText)
            
            return filteredText
        }
```

whole page source:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/5/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
    <script>
        const cleanElements = /(<+[a-z]*\s)+(.*?)>/g
        var cleantext = false
        var blacklist 
        var whitelist = ["a", "div", "code"]

        if (typeof cleantext !== 'undefined'){
            if (cleantext === true){
                //do something
            }
            else if (cleantext === false){
                //do something
            }
        }
        else{
            alert("'cleantext' is undefined, set to false")
            cleantext = false
        }

        const filterText = (text) => {
            let filteredText = text
                var regex2 = new RegExp("<(\/?).*?>", "gi");
                console.log(text)
                const tags = text.match(/<(\/?).*?>/gi);
                console.log(tags)
                for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                    let matchez = false
                    for (let q = 0; q < whitelist.length; q++) {
                        var regex = new RegExp("<(\/?)" + whitelist[q] + ".*?>", "gi");
                        if (tags[i].match(regex)){
                            console.log(tags[i] + " " + i)
                            matchez = true
                            console.log(matchez)
                        }
                        else{
                            console.log(tags[i])
                        }
                    }
                    if (matchez === false){
                        filteredText = filteredText.replace(tags[i], "")
                    }
                } 
                console.log(filteredText)
            
            return filteredText
        }

        if (typeof blacklist !== 'undefined'){
            if (blacklist === true){
                //do something
            }
            else if (blacklist === false){
                //do something
            }
        }
        else{
            alert("'blacklist' is undefined")
        }
        
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#mytextarea',
            plugins: 'paste, code',
            toolbar: 'edit, code',
            paste_block_drop: false,
            paste_tab_spaces: 2,
            paste_as_text: cleantext,
                paste_preprocess: function (plugin, args) {
                    args.content = args.content.replace(cleanElements, "$1>")
                    //if (blacklist){
                        args.content = filterText(args.content)
                    //}
                }
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <textarea style="height: 50rem;" id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>

</body>

</html>
```